# SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length

Tags: apache, ssl, opensuse

I looked at [this question][1]

[1]: [SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538723/ssl-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-permissible-length-error-code) Although that does not work for me.

So I have SSL installed on my apache server (OpenSuSe) although no SSl certificate.
When ever i go to the site with https I get this:

Secure Connection Failed

```
      An error occurred during a connection to 123.123.123.123.
```

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)

My listen.conf says this:

```
<IfDefine SSL>
<IfDefine !NOSSL>
    <IfModule mod_ssl.c>
        Listen 443
    </IfModule>
</IfDefine>
```

Listen 80

ANy ideas? this is really annoying to me.

Comment: You need a certificate. It's pointless to test anything without one.

Comment: But it was working before, and i didnt have a certificate.