# ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR not able to see https localhost pages in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, localhost

Not able to see the localhost https page properly in chrome . It says :

```
**This site can’t provide a secure connection**
localhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I tried -deleting domain localhost from - `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`
But not helped.

Comment: What HTTPS server are you running?

Comment: I am using IBM HTTP Server. And this is used in a websphere commerce localhost environment

Comment: This issue might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538723/ssl-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-permissible-length-error-code

Answer (score 43):

Go to **chrome://net-internals** in the Chrome and switch to the **Domain Security Policy** tab.

In the "**Delete domain security policies**" section at the bottom, write "localhost" in Domain field and press the "Delete" button.

Note, this is a temporary fix.

Comment: Why is it temporary ? what to do for it to stay?

Comment: Chrome is about to become a secondary browser for me! :/ But thanks for the fix! <3

Answer (score 22):

Instead of

```
localhost:8000
```

Write

```
http://localhost:8000/
```

**Note:** replace 8000 with your port number

Answer (score 17):

What worked for me was using http://127.0.0.1:3000/ ([its DNS entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7382631/3559330)) instead of http://localhost:3000/

Answer (score 13):

Try clearing your website data and cache from chrome. Old htaccess files can cause problems on localhost.

Comment: Clearing the cache of my browser worked for me. I am able to resolve the above error by clearing the cache.

Comment: Alternatively, you can open a Chrome session in incognito mode. 
shortkeys: [Ctrl + Shift + N]

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Visual Studio

Then go to project properties => enable SSL as True and select the SSL URL with port number
[Showed as per the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLsIG.jpg)

Comment: For .NET Core, this was down the bottom in the debug tab when you go to the project properties.

Answer (score 7):

Changing `https` to `http` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

1. I cleared Google Cache on Chrome://settings/privacy
2. Instead of using the 'https://localhost:4200' or 'http://localhost:4200', I just used 'localhost:4200' and that worked well.

Answer (score 3):

If for any reason your `localhost` keep being redirected to `https` [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/869739/1744228) might help you.

1. Change https to http **(But do not hit enter)**
2. Click and hold the reload icon
3. Choose the 3rd option *Empty Cache and Hard Reload*
   [image: Answer explanation]

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

```
localhost:8000
```

Replace

```
127.0.0.1:8000
```

you try to use the local port number

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my antivirus was the culprit. Somehow the site was considered unsafe and it replaced the response with the 'website blocked' page of the antivirus application. This information, however, was not sent with TLS so the browser interpreted that as an ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [**Disable cache**](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/network/reference/#disable-cache) checkbox (checking it *on*) in the `Network` pane of Chrome's DevTools.

[image: Disable cache screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

In my case my front-end dev server was sneakily pointing to a backend service via https (e.g. `API_URL=https://localhost:3001`)

Answer (score 0):

change 'https' to 'http'. It worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

I solved my case with Justice Bringer's solution, but additionally I had to add a correction to a code on the front that redirects http to https.

```
if (window.location.protocol !== '4200') {
     forceHttps();
};

// force-to-https.js v1
function forceToHttps() {
    if (location.protocol == 'http:') {
        var linkHttps = location.href.replace('http', 'https');
        // via location
        window.location.protocol = 'https:';
        window.location.href = linkHttps;
        // via click
        var a = document.createElement('a');
        a.setAttribute('href', linkHttps);
        a.setAttribute('style', 'display: none !important;');
        a.click();
        // reinforce
        setInterval(function() {
            window.location.href = linkHttps;
            a.click();
        }, 3500);
        // via meta
        var meta = document.createElement('meta');
        meta.setAttribute('content', '0;URL=' + linkHttps);
        meta.setAttribute('http-equiv', 'refresh');
        (document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0]).append(meta);
    };
};
```

Answer (score -2):

[This](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/348896) solution worked for me.

Adding `fake` parameter to query string fixes the problem.

e.g. http://localhost:3000/?fake=true

Answer (score -3):

`chrome://flags` -> `https` and then set it to `enable`

works to me

Comment: You should not just ask to turn off the HTTPS.