API endpoint working in all browsers but Chrome
C# API Application in .Net 6 run in VS 2022
When I debug and run locally - hit the following endpoint in a browser:
http://localhost:54471/api/Books/GetBooks
This works in FF and Edge and I can step through the code but when I use chrome I get :
This site can’t provide a secure connectionlocalhost sent an invalid response.
Try running Windows Network Diagnostics.
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

chrome version: Version 123.0.6312.106
does anyone know why?, or how to disable this?

Why would you get an SSL Protocol Error with a http URL? That would only make sense if you had an https url.

I cant figure it out either

Related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48076363/err-ssl-protocol-error-not-able-to-see-https-localhost-pages-in-chrome-browser

Try completely clearing your history. If you previously connected Chrome to a different localhost site with SSL it's likely remembering localhost generically as being an SSL site and automatically trying to redirect you.
