# Selenium firefox driver forces https

Tags: selenium, docker, ssl, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have a functional app running in a docker on port `3000`. I have selenium tests that works when I set my host to `http://localhost:3000`. I created a container to launch the selenium tests and it fails with the following error:

```
WebDriverError:Reachederrorpage:about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=https://app:3000/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=An error occurred during a connection to app:3000.

SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.

Error code: <a id="errorCode" title="SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG">SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG</a>
```

Snippet of my `docker-compose.yml`

```
app:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.dev
    volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
        - "3001:3001"
    networks:
        tests:

selenium-tester:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile.selenium.tests
    volumes:
        - ./:/usr/src/app/
        - /dev/shm:/dev/shm
    depends_on:
        - app
    networks:
        tests:
```

I replaced the host by `http://app:3000` but firefox seems to want to redirect this http to https (which is not working). And finally I build my driver like this:

```
const ffoptions = new firefox.Options()
  .headless()
  .setPreference('browser.urlbar.autoFill', 'false'); // test to disable auto https redirect… not working obviously
const driver = Builder()
      .setFirefoxOptions(ffoptions)
      .forBrowser('firefox')
      .build();
```

When manually contacting the `http://app:3000` using `curl` inside the selenium-tester container it works as expected, I get my homepage.

I'm short on ideas now and even decomposing my problem to write this question  didn't get me new ones

Answer (score 7):

I had exactly the same problem - couldn't successfully make request on HTTP to app from Selenium-controlled browsers (Chrome or Firefox) in other Docker container on same network. cURL from that container though worked fine! Connect on HTTP, but something seemed to be trying to force HTTPS. Identical situation right down to the name of the container "app".

The answer is... it's the name of the container!

"app" is a top level domain on the HSTS preloaded list - that is, browsers will force access through HTTPS.

Fix is to use a container name that isn't on HSTS preloaded lists.

[HSTS - more reading](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security)

Comment: oh my good lord.  thank you internet stranger, i have no idea how long it might have taken me to figure this out without you.

Comment: A truly horrible gotcha, that's for sure... I'm glad my pain at least meant someone else didn't need to suffer as much!

Comment: if you - like me - don't want to change your service name, you could also add an alias so the selenium browsers can connect to your app service via an alternative hostname:
`services:
  app:
    networks:
        tests:
          aliases:
            - app.local`

Comment: For future visitors also driven crazy by this, you can check a name at https://hstspreload.org/ to see if it is in the HSTS preloaded list.

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned *manually contacting the http://app:3000 using curl inside the selenium-tester container it works as expected*

This error message...

```
WebDriverError:Reachederrorpage:about:neterror?e=nssFailure2&u=https://app:3000/&c=UTF-8&f=regular&d=An error occurred during a connection to app:3000.
SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.
Error code: <a id="errorCode" title="SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG">SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG</a>
```

...implies that SSL layer in curl or one of its dependencies seems broken.

@RussellFulton in this [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538723/ssl-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-permissible-length-error-code) mentioned:

> This seems to be the result you see from *Firefox* when the server is not configured properly for SSL. Possibly *Chrome* would have just gave a generic **`ssl failed`** error.

This can happen when the browser sends a *SSL handshake* when the server is expecting an HTTP request. Server responds with a **400 code** and an *error message* that is much bigger that the *handshake message* that the browser expects. Hence you see the message.

---

### Reasons and Solution

- When the error prone code tries to redirect to HTTPS on port 80 (port 3000 in your case).

  - Solution: Removing the port 80 (port 3000 in your case) from the url, the redirect works.

> **HTTPS** by default runs over port **443**.

- This error also occurs when you have enabled the SSL module.

  - Solution: You have run `a2enmod ssl`.

    a2enmod ssl
    //or
    a2ensite default-ssl
- Provided a wrong **IP** in the *ssl config*.

  - Solution: Changed IP to what it should be.
- Remove the **IP** if not needed in the *ssl config*.

  - Solution: Change

    VirtualHost your.domain.com:443
    //to
    VirtualHost *default*:443
- [curl: (35) SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length.](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1506395) issue was discussed at length.
- As per **Curl** [Support HTTPS proxy and SOCKS+HTTP(s)](https://github.com/curl/curl/pull/1127) there was another attempt to get the HTTPS proxy support into Curl.
- This [curl commit](https://github.com/curl/curl/commit/74ffa040a44267c35be98d057c8ebd82b6b5be3c) should have addressed your issue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I'm not using any apache in this, just 2 dockers, the first running my app on port 3000 and the second launching tests. No SSL involved either. My problem is that firefox is trying to reach `https://app:3000` while I ask for `http://app:3000`. Nothing is configured for SSL and I don't wan't to do it. I just want firefox to stay on http and reach my app on port 3000. And finally I stated that curl works perfectly, no problem with it, it doesn't try to fetch SSL and it reaches my site on port 3000 just fine getting me my homepage. Anymore lead is welcome :)