# Failure to access service after running kiwi with docker due to the ssl configuration I guess

Tags: kiwi-tcms

I am trying to use Kiwi to manage my testcase.
I follow exactly the steps in [this](https://kiwitcms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing_docker.html#) documentation

After I startup the service by using docker-compose up, these logs shown in my terminal:

---

```
kiwi_web | AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
kiwi_web | [Tue Jan 08 08:40:42.574498 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 10] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 172.20.0.3:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
kiwi_web | [Tue Jan 08 08:40:42.574972 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 10] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 172.20.0.3:8443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
kiwi_web | AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.20.0.3. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
kiwi_web | [Tue Jan 08 08:40:42.613817 2019] [auth_digest:notice] [pid 10] AH01757: generating secret for digest authentication ...
kiwi_web | [Tue Jan 08 08:40:42.614733 2019] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 10] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
kiwi_web | [Tue Jan 08 08:40:42.615950 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 10] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 172.20.0.3:443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
kiwi_web | [Tue Jan 08 08:40:42.616228 2019] [ssl:warn] [pid 10] AH01909: RSA certificate configured for 172.20.0.3:8443 does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
kiwi_web | [Tue Jan 08 08:40:42.621818 2019] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 10] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips mod_wsgi/4.6.5 Python/3.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
kiwi_web | [Tue Jan 08 08:40:42.621878 2019] [core:notice] [pid 10] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

When I try to access the service through web browser I get the following error message:

```
 Failure to establish secure connection
    SSL receives a record that exceeds the maximum allowable length. Error  code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG
```

Actually I don't really need https protocal, how can I disable it and just use http?

Answer (score 1):

The log from Apache is expected. We don't know the FQDN of the instance running Kiwi TCMS and this is not configured. However this should not stop it from working. After all this is how we run on the live demo.

The second error is described here:
[SSL received a record that exceeded the maximum permissible length. (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538723/ssl-received-a-record-that-exceeded-the-maximum-permissible-length-error-code)

It points to a bug in Firefox and possibly some misconfiguration on the server side. However without additional info there's nothing I can do to help.

Are you trying to use the default SSL certificates or provide your own ?

Comment: thanks, it works fine now after I change my browser to chrome and ignore the security warning.